# Issues in converting SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have a sql query like below (table and column names are arbitrary for the sake of question):

```
select t3.MRIID as 'Ids'
from table1 t1  
    join table2 t2 with (nolock) on t1.ID = t2.SPID
    join table3 t3 with (nolock) on t2.ID = t3.SPMRID
    join table4 t4 on t4.MRID = t3.MRID
where 
    t3.MRISID = 18
    and t1.ID = 315
group by t3.MRIID
having SUM(CAST(t4.IRGPC AS INT)) > 0
```

I am trying to convert this to an equivalent LINQ query and this is what I have so far. This does not give me the intended result when I run it in LINQPad and was wondering if anyone has explanation to where I am going wrong? I know my group/having clauses are the issues here but not sure how to solve it.

```
from t1 in table1
    join t2 in table2 on t1.ID equals t2.SPID
    join t3 in table3 on t2.ID equals t3.SPMRID
    join t4 in table4 on t3.MRID equals t4.ID
where t3.MRISID == 18 && t1.ID == 315
group new { t1, t2, t3, t4 } by t3.MRID into groupedResult
let count = groupedResult.Count()
where count > 0
select new { Something = groupedResult.Key}
```

The SQL query gives me 2 'Ids' in result which is expected as compared to Linq query giving me 3 out of which 1 'Id' does not match the `having` clause

Help greatly appreciated!

[UPDATE] I just noticed my having clause in sql query is not what is there in Linq equivalent and am trying to understand how to accomplish that?

Based on Mrinal's solution (and chat comments), My LINQ now stands at

```
from t1 in table1
    join t2 in table2 on t1.ID equals t2.SPID
    join t3 in table3 on t2.ID equals t3.SPMRID
    join t4 in table4 on t3.MRID equals t4.ID
where t3.MRISID == 18 && t1.ID == 315
group Convert.ToInt32(cd.IRGPC) by mriw.MRIID into groupedResult
where groupedResult.Sum() > 0
select new { groupedResult.Key}
```

However, this is still not matching the results of what the original SQL statement gives. I Ran this linq query through LinqPad to see the generated SQL and it looks like below.

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 18
DECLARE @p1 Int = 315
DECLARE @p2 Int = 0
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t5].[MRIID] AS [Key]
FROM (
    SELECT SUM([t4].[value]) AS [value], [t4].[MRIID]
    FROM (
        SELECT CONVERT(Int,[t3].[IRGPC]) AS [value], [t2].[MRISID], [t0].[ID], [t2].[MRIID]
        FROM [table1] AS [t0]
        INNER JOIN [table2] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ID] = [t1].[SPID]
        INNER JOIN [table3] AS [t2] ON [t1].[ID] = [t2].[SPMRID]
        INNER JOIN [table4] AS [t3] ON [t2].[MRIID] = [t3].[ID]
        ) AS [t4]
    WHERE ([t4].[MRISID] = @p0) AND ([t4].[ID] = @p1)
    GROUP BY [t4].[MRIID]
    ) AS [t5]
WHERE [t5].[value] > @p2
```

If this extra bit of detail helps, the `IRGPC` column is a `bit` type in SQL and `bool` type in C# code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I cannot comment on the exact issue but you may not need the group new { t1, t2, t3, t4 }.  You may only need your table you do the aggregate on 't3'.  You may be creating duplicates do to that.  You should also be able to see SQL results I believe if you are using Linqpad, I am rusty as I have not used it in a while.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? Do you have your relationships set-up correctly and are you certain you need to use Joins instead of Navigation Properties?

Comment: I doubt EF translates anything into a `having` statement.  More likely you'll get a subquery that is further filtered on the sum.  So you'd want `where groupedResults.Sum(x => (int)x.t4.IRGPC) > 0` or something close to that.

Comment: Your `GroupedResult` Where condition shall be `where `groupedResult.Sum(y => y.t4.IRGPC) > 0`, id it has to be inline with the Sql query `having SUM(CAST(t4.IRGPC AS INT)) > 0  `

Comment: I actually think you only need `t4.IRGPC` in your group so you can filter on the sum and you'd just select `t3.MRID` via the `Key` like you are already doing.

Comment: Why are you doing `Count()` in LINQ but `SUM` in SQL?

Comment: For a C# boolean why would you consider `Sum`, it should comparison with boolean values, true / false. In Sql Server 0 would mean false and 1 true

Comment: I need a sum because I am trying to determine if any one of the returned records have this column value to be true. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's what I mean, you are looking for just one value in the complete grouping which is true and that key is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying the Linq query as follows:

```
from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2 on t1.ID equals t2.SPID
join t3 in table3 on t2.ID equals t3.SPMRID
join t4 in table4 on t3.MRID equals t4.ID
where t3.MRISID == 18 && t1.ID == 315
group new { t1, t2, t3, t4 } by t3.MRID into groupedResult
where groupedResult.Sum(y => (int)y.t4.IRGPC) > 0
select new { Something = groupedResult.Key }
```

**Modification:**

Changed the `groupedResult.Count() > 0` to `groupedResult.Sum(y => (int)y.t4.IRGPC) > 0`, since in the Sql query you have `having SUM(CAST(t4.IRGPC AS INT)) > 0`, which needs to replicated in the Linq Query

**EDIT 1:**

As mentioned by OP, `t4.IRGPC` is a boolean type and use case is to get one grouping, which has at least one value true, try the following option:

```
group t4.IRGPC by t3.MRID into groupedResult
where groupedResult.Any(x => x)
```

Comment: I am trying the solution you provided and will get back.Thanks Mrinal!

Comment: The grouping can be simplified to just `group t4.IRGPC by t3.MRID into groupedResult` then the second filter is just `where groupedResults.Sum(y => (int)y) > 0`

Comment: @juharr You'll lose the projection of other tables.

Comment: @vendettamit They're not needed beyond the joins unless the OP left anything out.

Comment: @juharr uhh.. I just saw the SQL statement. Great suggestion.

Comment: That's a valid suggestion if the projections are not required, which seems to be the case, we can Cast to int in the grouping itself, 
`group (int)t4.IRGPC by t3.MRID into groupedResult
  where groupedResult.Sum(y => y) > 0`

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect what I have done based on suggestions provided here. The results still do not match. Any clue?

Comment: @adityap considering the bit / boolean type for Sum may not be a good strategy, as I understand you are looking for a group key, where at least 1 value is true, since in sql server 1 - true and 0 - false

Comment: Thanks for point that out @MrinalKamboj. That helps simplify things now that I think about it. Just trying few things before I call it the answer, will get back!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
let count = groupedResult.Count()
where count > 0
```

use where clause

```
where groupedResult.Sum(x => x.t4.IRGPC) > 0
```